# Pytest + Multiprocessing Queue don't play well together

Tags: python, queue, pytest, python-multiprocessing

I'm pytesting a multi-queue. My test involves a simple class with a getter and setter, wrapping around a multi-queue.

My test alternates between pass and fail as I re-run i [edit: this occurs when using block=False. Setting it to True as recommended hangs the program].

How do I re-write this so as to

(1) clear the multi-queue between program executions and
(2) Read all the values from the queue in the .get() method?

```
import multiprocessing
import queue

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.results = []

    def put(self, x):
        self.q.put(x)

    def get(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.results.append(self.q.get(block=True))
            except queue.Empty:
                break
        return self.results

    @pytest.fixture
    def wrapped_queue():
        yield MyClass()

    def test_multiprocessing_queue(wrapped_queue):
        wrapped_queue.put("a")
        wrapped_queue.put("b")
        result = wrapped_queue.get()
        assert result == ["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an issue with pytest. There's more going on behind the scenes with queue than you realize.

If you set `block=True` in your getter, it should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you - In the example I left out the fact that I am getting multiple items from the queue. Using block=True freezes my program. I have updated the snippet to reflect this

Comment: The addition of the "while True" statement changes everything. It's now blocking because you call get() with an empty Queue that you haven't closed. Is your example leaving out some code that uses a process pool?

Comment: The actual program receives messages from another process. I don't use a process pool anywhere. In my test, I'm not running this second process.

Comment: You might have too high of expectations for python multithreading. The documentation provides little in the way of guarantees. When you call "put", the value isn't immediately available to "get", which is why you need the blocking call. I'm not 100% sure of your exact need here, but looking at the CPython implementation might help: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py

Comment: The docs say that multiprocess.queue.get(block=True) will wait until a value arrives. I just need to check the queue and move on if there is nothing new there. Should I be doing things differently?